# Google Apps Scripts / Google Sheet - Disable all the active filters, Show a specific cell and filter again based on criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to create a custom menu in my spreadsheet that will have 2 items:

1st item:

- Disable all the active filters in a specific sheet.
- Show the last empty row in column B (in my example sheet: cell
  B15)
- Add the value "> Add Content here <" in the last empty cell from column B

2nd item: Filtering the data using filter from column B & C and keep only the data for the last 60 days (It would be nice if the code is dynamic).

I've started to work on the first item, but I'm stuck at the second part.
Here is a sample of my spreadsheet with GAS to help you understand what I want to achieve.

https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1rVwI5QMA35PksB9csKvMhxWpCHeLEbdKAo5UWb8y9GFGtdHpHsOwkva6/edit

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ptkjp5UySKc0iwZTu3QUrJVKds6t4W5eMD39XVUbME/edit#gid=0

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put a value of `> Add Content here <` to the 1st empty row of column "B".
- You want to show the rows that the year and month values of columns "B" and "C" are the last 60 days.
- You want to achieve this filter using the basic filter.

When I saw your sample script, I found the following sample script.

```js
// first item - working
function prepareForContentAddition() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) {  
    var range = filter.getRange(); 
    var firstColumn = range.getColumn();
    var lastColumn = range.getLastColumn();
    for (var i = firstColumn; i < lastColumn; i++) {
      filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(i);
    }
  }
// Show the last empty row / blank cell in Column B and add "> Add Content here <" in it
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange('Dashboard!B3:B').getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, +1,1).activate();
}

// Apply 2 months filtering starting from today
function backToFiltering() {
}
```

When this script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function prepareForContentAddition() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) {
    var range = filter.getRange();
    var firstColumn = range.getColumn();
    var lastColumn = range.getLastColumn();
    for (var i = firstColumn; i < lastColumn; i++) {
      filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(i);
    }
  }

  // I added below script.
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) { // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };
  var row = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(2);
  sheet.getRange(row + 1, 2).setValue("> Add Content here <");
}
```

And

```js
function backToFiltering() {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 60);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) {
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(year).build()).setColumnFilterCriteria(3, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(month).build());
  }
}
```

- In this modification, I think that your expected situation can be obtained. `2022, 8` and `2022, 9` are shown. But, when you want to show `2022, 7`, `2022, 8` and `2022, 9`, please modify them as follows.

  - From

    ```
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(year).build()).setColumnFilterCriteria(3, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(month).build());
    ```
  - To

    ```
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(2, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(year).build()).setColumnFilterCriteria(3, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(month).build());
    ```

#### References:

- [Class FilterCriteriaBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder)
- [setColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition, filterCriteria)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , thank you so much, it works perfectly and that's exactly what I needed.
For the first function, I added an extra piece of code to the script (-> activate):  `sheet.getRange(row + 1, 2).setValue("> Add Content here <").activate();` So users can be automatically redirected to this particular sheet and row where "> Add Content here <" is written.

Comment: @Damien Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.